# Mathematica 10 Dataset doesn't format more than 4 columns?

Tags: version-10, dataset

Try this code in Mathematica 10:

```
Dataset@Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[4]], {2}]
```

I got a nicely formatted table:

[image]

But when I do the same thing for 5 columns, it won't get formatted at all:

```
Dataset@Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[5]], {2}]
```

gives:

[image]

Is that what supposed to be? Don't you think 4 column is a pretty stingy limitation?

[*Note: In V12, this limitation has been removed and all columns are shown. Even all 125 columns of `Dataset@Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[125]], {2}]`.*  --@Michael E2]

Comment: What you see is similar to the output of the model fit functions and TimeSeries for instance. You get a summary object that symbolizes the data structure but is not meant to fully represent it visually. For formatting tables we have things like Grid or TableForm.

Comment: Is there a method similar to FullForm or options for Dataset that attempts to display more of the structure? It also crops rows if there are many.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Are you aware of any new functions that are specifically meant for formatting Dataset and won't require extracting both the tabular data and the headers separately?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm afraid not.

Comment: I posted some work around function `viewDataset` for tabular datasets [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61030/show-more-rows-of-dataset/85531#85531).

Comment: Hi, I updated the question to reflect how it works now, in V12.  Roll back if you disapprove.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Theoretically, Dataset supports any number of columns.

The behavior you are seeing is actually because the type deduction that Dataset is doing behind the scenes isn't perfect (and indeed in some sense *cannot* be perfect). Your synthetic example is such that your second list of associations is "most consistent" with a particular type that doesn't typeset as a table.

You can see what type Dataset deduced in a given case by using `` Dataset`GetType ``. First get `TypeSystem` onto your context path, so that the types aren't fully qualified and are easier to read:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"];
```

Then use `GetType`:

```
In[2]:= Dataset`GetType @ Dataset @ Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[4]], {2}]
Out[2]= Vector[Struct[{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
 {Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer]}], 2]
```

Notice that the type of your data has been deduced to be a `Vector` (homogenous list) of `Structs`s (heterogenous associations), or in other words a row-oriented table.

But now do:

```
In[3]:= Dataset`GetType @ Dataset @ Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[5]], {2}]
Out[3]= Vector[Assoc[Atom[String], Atom[Integer], 5], 2]
```

Here, your data has been deduced as a `Vector` of `Assoc`s (homogenous associations). `Assocs` are a type that doesn't care what keys are present, just that they all have the same type, and also that the values have the same type.

That happened because according to the internal heuristics, an `Assoc` is considered to be a more parsimonious type as soon as we cross the threshold of 4 fields. But this would not be true if we looked at an association whose values were different types, instead of all being integers:

```
In[2]:= DeduceType @ Table[<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3, "D" -> 4, "E" -> "bar"|>, {5}]
Out[2]= Vector[Struct[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}, 
  {Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[String]}], 5]
```

The only consistent type here is a `Vector` of `Structs` (notice I'm using `DeduceType` directly, which is what Dataset uses upon construction). And indeed, this more complex Dataset typesets as a table, owing to the inner `Struct` type:

[image: Dataset]

Although it isn't documented and is therefore of course subject to change, you can force a specific type to be used by supplying a second argument to Dataset:

```
Dataset[
  Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[5]], {5}], 
  Vector[Struct[{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, 
    {Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer], Atom[Integer]}]]]
```

This will typeset as a table, as you desire:

[image: dataset-row-oriented]

Comment: Does the internal Dataset structure only affect its Format or other operations as well?

Comment: @alancalvitti 4 is really just a codification of my prior belief in the likelihood of different forms of data. The Dataset type ('schema' might be a better word) is used for formatting, and also validation. If you try an invalid query it'll stop you shooting yourself in the foot, with a (hopefully) helpful error message telling you why. In the future it'll also be used for autocomplete prediction and NLP queries against data.

Comment: I think we all appreciate the new functionality. However, working w real datasets, I resort to // Normal and subsequent operations. The built in format is too limiting. At least make it interactive so users can choose thresholds in Level and other dimensions.

Comment: @alancalvitti formatting of Dataset will get better (and more interactive) over time

Comment: This is a very helpful post.  While the concept makes some sense, I have doubts that the cutoff at 4 for the table format is the right one.  Here's a little Dataset that in my view formats the "wrong way" by default.Dataset[{<|"id" -> 1, "x" -> 0.2`, "y" -> 1.3`, "z" -> 1.4`, 
   "p" -> 0.23`, "c" -> 0.16`, "\[Epsilon]" -> 0, 
   "u" -> 0.2518012417419029`, "purchaseQ" -> 0, 
   "\[Xi]" -> 0.2`|>, <|"id" -> 2, "x" -> 0.5`, "y" -> 2.3`, 
   "z" -> 3.4`, "p" -> 0.23`, "c" -> 0.16`, "\[Epsilon]" -> 0.16`, 
   "u" -> 0.39`, "purchaseQ" -> 1, "\[Xi]" -> 0.2902109575703712`|>}

Comment: Do I understanding it right that changing the schema won't have any other consequences at the moment than changing formatting (and error messages), but might have more disruptive consequences in the future?  It looks like what people want here is just useful formatting, so perhaps what's needed is a separate easy-to-use function that's just used for display, while letting Dataset format as a summary by default (i.e. as it does now).

Comment: *Automatically* displaying *everything* can be bad: e.g. `Graph` computes a graph layout automatically even for large graphs and it can be extremely slow or not able to finish at all in a reasonable time.

Comment: The definitions associated with ``TypeSystem`AnyLength`` are a bit weird.  `Plus[___, a, ___]` is in fact equivalent to `Plus[a, ___]` because of the attributes of `Plus`.  The same is true for `Times`.  `Minus` is a single-argument function, so that definition was probably meant to use `Subtract`.  Yet `Subtract` is not needed because `x - y` *parses* directly to `Plus[x, Times[-1, y]]` and never gets interpreted as `Subtract`.

Comment: @Szabolcs well spotted. Fixed.

Comment: @SethChandler I will make some effort to improve these heuristics for 10.0.2. I think I can do a bit better for the cases that are showing up here...

Comment: @SethChandler @Szabolcs @alancalvitti Okay, so this is 'fixed' in 10.0.2! The heuristics in `DeduceType` are quite a bit smarter now, and they'll generally lean towards `Struct` over `Assoc`.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon any word on when 10.0.2 will be released?

Comment: @Zack It might be as late as January, because of the holiday slowdown.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at `InputForm`s of produced `Dataset`s you will see significant difference:

```
Dataset@Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[4]], {2}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Dataset[{<|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4|>, 
>          <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4|>}, 
>  TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Struct[{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
>    {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
>     TypeSystem`Atom[Integer]}], 2], <|"ID" -> 34613158063874|>]
> ```

```
Dataset@Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[5]], {2}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Dataset[{<|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>, 
>          <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>}, 
>  TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Assoc[TypeSystem`Atom[String], 
>    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 5], 2], <|"ID" -> 93437030149901|>]
> ```

Let us try to reproduce the first structure with 5 columns:

```
Dataset[Table[Association[ToString[#] -> # & /@ Range[5]], {2}], 
 TypeSystem`Vector[
  TypeSystem`Struct[ToString /@ Range[5], 
   Table[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], {5}]], 2]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Voilà! I have checked this method with 200 columns and it works!

Comment: Is there a way to override the built in Format for Dataset? Anything is better than this, eg // Normal // TableForm

Comment: AFAIK currently there is no simple way to change the style of `Dataset` in `StandardForm` other than re-implementing `Format[Dataset]`. Such questions of course should be asked to the developer, [Taliesin Beynon](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7140/taliesin-beynon), not me.

Comment: @alancalvitti I don't see why we shouldn't let you set a customer formatter. I'll add it to my list.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, thanks, look forward. Despite its limits, Dataset is a great product that is already making query dev faster, more compact and flexible.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, for some data shapes like 2-dim relational tables I use `// Normalize // TableForm` with headers based on the Keys. So it's simple. But why doesn't Unprocting `Dataset` and then `UpSet` `Format`, work?

Comment: I have not tried it myself. But you don't need to Unprotect Dataset, you should override the built-in Format rules which you can see with FormatValues[Dataset]. If you want to explore it deeper please create separate question.

Comment: Please put custom formatter high on your list ;)  At the very least, some interim documentation on this issue would be helpful so that users do not tear their remaining hair out and think they have done something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I think that ideally there would be a separate function for displaying a dataset in the preferred way.  Automatic formatting should only produce a summary, i.e. truncate the data if it is too large.  But we should have the option to display the complete dataset and tweak the way it is displayed, if necessary.

---

This is an attempt at writing a function that will take a dataset having the form of a 2D table and will try to format it in a reasonable way.  It doesn't aim to be general and will probably fail on more complicated datasets.  The way I'm trying to determine the type (schema) is probably clumsy, and I'll take any suggestions on how to do this better (I'm sure there are undocumented functions to do this properly).

Basic usage:

```
ds = Dataset[Association["a" -> Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> 2], "b" -> Association["a" -> 3, "b" -> 4]]];

formatDS[ds]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is extended from something for my own use, hence the small font size and the `RotateLabel` option.  People might want to tweak at least the font size when using this.

---

```
ClearAll[formatDS]
Options[formatDS] = {RotateLabel -> False};
formatDS[ds_Dataset, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {$headerColour, $frameColour,
   hasRowKeys, hasColKeys,
   colKeys, rowKeys, content,
   rot, type, form}
  ,
  $headerColour = GrayLevel[0.9];
  $frameColour = GrayLevel[0.8];
  type = Dataset`GetType@Dataset@Normal[ds]; (* force re-compute type *)
  hasRowKeys = MatchQ[type, HoldPattern[Assoc[_Atom, __] | _Struct]];
  hasColKeys = 
   MatchQ[type, 
    HoldPattern[
     Assoc[_Atom, _Assoc | _Struct, ___] | 
      Vector[_Assoc | _Struct, ___]]];
  If[hasRowKeys, rowKeys = Normal@ds[Keys]];
  If[hasColKeys, colKeys = Normal@ds[1, Keys]];
  rot = If[TrueQ@OptionValue[RotateLabel], Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, 
    Identity];
  Which[
   hasRowKeys && hasColKeys,
   content = Normal@ds[Values, Values];
   form = Sequence[ArrayFlatten[( {
        {Null, {rot /@ colKeys}},
        {List /@ rowKeys, content}
       } )], Background -> {{$headerColour}, {$headerColour}}];
   ,
   hasRowKeys,
   content = Normal@ds[Values];
   form = 
    Sequence[ArrayFlatten[{{List /@ rowKeys, content}}], 
     Background -> {{$headerColour}, None}];
   ,
   hasColKeys,
   content = Normal@ds[All, Values];
   form = Sequence[ArrayFlatten[( {
        {{rot /@ colKeys}},
        {content}
       } )], Background -> {None, {$headerColour}}];
   ,
   True, form = content = Normal[ds]
   ];
  Style[
   Grid[
    form,
    Frame -> All,
    FrameStyle -> $frameColour,
    Spacings -> {1, 1},
    ItemSize -> Full
    ],
   "Text", FontSize -> 10
   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a cheap and dirty function that takes a Vector of Associations variant of a Dataset and converts it into a Vector of Structs. No guarantees this actually works on a variety of Datasets, but it worked for me.  If the keys in each element of the Dataset are not the same, this function will not work properly.

```
 structDisplay[d_Dataset] := Module[{struct1, types},
 Needs["TypeSystem`"];
 struct1 = Normal@Keys[d[1]];
 types = 
 Replace[DeleteDuplicates /@ 
 Transpose[Map[DeduceType, Normal[Values /@ d], {2}]], {{t_} :> 
  t, {t_, u__} :> AnyType}, 1];
 Dataset[Normal@d, Vector[Struct[struct1, types], Length[d]]]
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the 4 column limit only applies to datasets that contain only numbers as values. For example:

```
Dataset[{
  <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> 1, "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>
  }]
```

returns

[image]

However, making all the values for 1 set of keys into strings:

```
Dataset[{
  <|"1" -> "1", "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> "1", "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> "1", "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> "1", "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>,
  <|"1" -> "1", "2" -> 2, "3" -> 3, "4" -> 4, "5" -> 5|>
  }]
```

returns the nicely formatted:

[image]

Changing 1 column to strings works for my particular application.

One question though remains: When would it be preferable to show a list of associations when each row contains exactly the same keys? I cannot think of a case where I would want that behavior.