# Can't get Append to append a record (association) to a dataset

Tags: bugs, core-language, dataset

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1 or earlier**

---

The Documentation Center item, [Computation with Structured Datasets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputationWithStructuredDatasets.html), implies that `Append` has been extended in V10 to work with datasets. But not on my computer. (I am running on OS X)

Here is what I tried:

```
ds = 
  Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>, 
           <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>}]
```

[image: dataset]

```
Append[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]
```

[image: failure]

However, insertion

```
Insert[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>, -1]
```

works fine.

[image: insert]

I don't know whether I've found a bug in `Append`in combination with a dataset or whether I am misreading the documentation. Are others experiencing what I am? Or can someone explain what I did wrong?

#### Update

I should have pointed out that I already knew that appending `Append[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>]` worked. But why does it fail when given an unbound symbol? And why should `Insert` behave differently when given an unbound symbol? Is V10 attempting to enforce some kind of a type consistency on the values of associations? That would be very un-*Mathematica* like.

Comment: It looks buggy to me given that `AppendTo[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]` works fine

Comment: Problem remains in version 10.0.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is interesting:

If you replace the symbol `y` with the string `"y"`, `Append` works fine.

```
Append[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y"|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, if you start out with `Symbol`s, then it works fine:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> x|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> y|>, <|
    "a" -> 3, "b" -> z|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> x|>}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then:

```
Append[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the **Undocumented** second argument we can force the `Dataset` on creation to expect `AnyType` of type:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"];

dst = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>, <|
    "a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>}, 
  Vector[Struct[{"a", "b"}, {Atom[Integer], AnyType}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now `Append` works even if we feed it a `Symbol` instead of a `String`:

```
Append[dst, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I already knew that "y" would work, but your find concerning `y` working if the other values of field "b" were symbols is new to me. +1

Comment: Your discussion of the undocumented 2nd does indicate an intent to enforce type consistency. But the implementation seem inconsistent, since `Append` enforces type consistency and `Insert` ignores it.

Comment: @m_goldberg. I agree. `Dataset` is clearly still buggy but seems to be a useful thing to have.

Comment: BTW, how did you learn about the existence of `TypeSystem` package? I can find nothing about it, not in the Documentation Center and not by search Google.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I learned about it from Taliesin Beynon in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54607/mathematica-10-dataset-doesnt-format-more-than-4-columns/54636#54636)

Comment: @m_goldberg This should 'coerce' the type of that column to become AnyType, rather than fail. I'll fix this, thanks for finding!

Answer (score 0):

very strange.

one way around is as follows:

```
list = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>, <|
    "a" -> 3, "b" -> "z"|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x"|>};
Dataset[Append[list, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]]
```

If it works in this way then it should work directly with `Append[ds, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> y|>]`

maybe it is a bug.