# Why does my dataset lose its typesetting when I add columns?

Tags: output-formatting, dataset

I've tried multiple methods of adding and removing columns to a dataset, but it seems no matter which way I choose I can't get the data to typeset as a table.

Here's my initial dataset:

[image]

1) Construct an association using `<|#, ... |>` syntax (with the `Normal` form to show that it yields a list of associations):

[image]

2) Using `Append[]`:

[image]

3) Using `JoinAcross[]`:

[image]

In each case, the dataset returns is typeset as a single row. Can anyone shed some light on as to why? I have a hunch that I'm fighting some kind of internal type system.  What's strange is given much simpler datasets, each one of these methods works fine.

Comment: The impact of type inference upon typesetting is discussed in detail [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54607/142).  There might be enough information there for the present question to be considered a duplicate.