# Blocking Dataset`$ElisionThreshold doesn't work

Tags: output-formatting, dataset, scoping

I would like to define a simple function to automatically show all rows in a `Dataset`. Based on [Taliesin Beynon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61458), I tried the following trivial snippet:

```
ClearAll[ShowDataset]
ShowDataset[{assoc__}, query__] := 
    Block[{Dataset`$ElisionThreshold = Length[{assoc}]*4},
        Dataset[Query[query]@{assoc}]
    ]
```

However, this doesn't work; the number of rows showed is still 16. On the other hand, `Block` does what it is supposed to do, because if I adjust the code to read

```
ClearAll[ShowDataset]
ShowDataset[{assoc__}, query__] := 
    Block[{Dataset`$ElisionThreshold = Length[{assoc}]*4},
    Dataset[Query[query]@{assoc}];
    Dataset`$ElisionThreshold
    ]
```

It shows the correct number of rows. Is this expected behaviour? Is there another way to temporarily and automatically set `` Dataset`$ElisionThreshold ``?

Comment: It may be helpful if you included a sample dataset, or even better, if you demonstrated your problem using one of the sample datasets provided by `ExampleData["Datasets"]`. Additionally, when you say that your second code snippet showed "the correct number of rows", did you mean to say that it showed the correct value of ``Dataset`$ElisionThreshold``?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resulting `Dataset` expression is typeset by the front-end after evaluation is complete.  This means that the `Block` expression has already been exited before typesetting occurs.  The value of `` Dataset`$ElisionThreshold `` is no longer being overridden as the dataset is being rendered.

One way to work around this is to use `Print` to force the typesetting to occur during evaluation:

```
ClearAll[ShowDataset2]
ShowDataset2[{assoc__}, query__] := 
    Block[{Dataset`$ElisionThreshold = Length[{assoc}]*4},
        Print @ Dataset[Query[query]@{assoc}]
    ]
```

This simple work-around comes at a cost: the return value of `ShowDataset2` is now `Null` instead of the dataset.

Usage:

```
$data = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}] // Normal;

ShowDataset2[$data, All]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Beware that the front-end sometimes has difficulty rendering large box structures such as the one in the example above.  I saw intermittent rendering glitches as a scrolled through my test notebook (using version 10.3 on Windows 7x64, emphasis on "intermittent").

**Update for Version 11**

Version 11 introduced a new style of dataset formatting.  The variable `` Dataset`$ElisionThreshold `` is not used in the new style -- `` Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount `` is used instead.  Alternatively, `` Dataset`$ElisionThreshold `` can still be used if we also set `` Dataset`$UseNewDatasetFormatting = False ``.

All of this remains undocumented and unsupported behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't work in 11.2

Comment: @yode In version 11, we must use ``Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount`` instead of ``Dataset`$ElisionThreshold``.  I have updated the response.

Comment: Ok, your magic works again. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use an output form:

```
Unprotect[$OutputForms];
AppendTo[$OutputForms, ShowDataset];
Protect[$OutputForms];

ShowDataset /: MakeBoxes[ShowDataset[ds_Dataset],StandardForm]:=Block[
    {Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount = Length[ds]},

    With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[ds]},
        InterpretationBox[
            boxes,
            ds
        ]
    ]
]
```

For example:

```
data = Dataset @ RandomReal[1, {25, 2}]
```

[image]

```
ShowDataset[data]
```

[image]

```
Head[%]
```

> Dataset

I used an [`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox) so that you can copy/paste the output.