# Increase number of rows displayed by Dataset

Tags: dataset, display

Is it possible to increase the number of rows (records) displayed by Dataset?  By default, only the first few rows are displayed.  Which, in many cases, is fine.  Especially for large datasets.  However, there are often occasions when the dataset I'm working with is of moderate size and I want to display all of it.  At present, I'm resorting to using Grid, but this adds work so I'd like to avoid if possible.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97534/5467)

Comment: Thanks very much, that does the job.