# Changing default display behaviour for Dataset

Tags: output-formatting, dataset, display

I have a function (whose [code is in this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103464)) to display `Dataset` in a more convenient way. To the extent that I never use the default one. I find myself constantly writing a code with a double entry:

```
allReportsWithDesc = 
  Query[Select[StringMatchQ[#Label, "[D0" ~~ ___] &], {"Label", 
     "Description"}]@dsNodes;
DisplayDatasetLive[allReportsWithDesc]
```

That is I suppress default output then use an alternative output.

I could write:

```
allReportsWithDesc = 
      Query[Select[StringMatchQ[#Label, "[D0" ~~ ___] &], {"Label", 
         "Description"}]@dsNodes;%//DisplayDatasetLive
```

I am wondering, however, if there was not a way to change the default display for `Dataset` to use `DisplayDatasetLive`. So I could write simply:

```
allReportsWithDesc = 
  Query[Select[StringMatchQ[#Label, "[D0" ~~ ___] &], {"Label", 
     "Description"}]@dsNodes
```

and the display would use `DisplayDatasetLive` (or some other function for that matter).

Comment: Look up `$Post`.

Comment: That's a useful functionality to know. So: $Post = If[Head[#] === Dataset, DisplayDatasetLive[#]] &; works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: You will want to actually use `If[Head[#] === Dataset, DisplayDatasetLive[#], #] &` so that other outputs are not affected.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks