# Do loop with If condition

Tags: export, conditional, procedural-programming

I have the following formulas:

1- A cross section:

```
sigma[beta_,alpha_,Y4_] := c^2/(256*Pi) * (1/2) ( Ytt[beta,alpha,Y4]/ m ) * Abs[A]^2
```

Where c is a strong coupling constant, m is a mass, A is a loop function and 
`Ytt[beta,alpha,Y4]` is a coupling .

2- A final cross section`fsigma`, which equals `sigma` times a branching ratio `BR`, that:

```
fsigma[beta_,alpha_,Y4_,xx_,ms_] := sigma[beta,alpha,Y4] * BR[beta,alpha,Y4,xx,ms]
```

I 'd like to generate a data file (.dat file), for the values of `fsigma` runs over the five free parameters, with each parameter has a region, as:

`{beta,ArcTan[0.9],ArcTan[2.],0.1}, {alpha,ArcTan[0.1],ArcTan[0.3],0.1}, 
{Y4,-1,-5,1},{xx,-7,7,1},{ms,350,400,50}`

**Also can I before making this loop**, to set a pre- defined constrain on `Ytt[beta,alpha,Y4] => 0.8 < Ytt[beta,alpha,Y4] < 1.2`. i.e., to select from the parameters domains only the points which satisfy this constrain.

I tried to use `Do` loop with `If` condition, but it doesn’t work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a table from a loop using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)

```
results =
    Reap[
      Do[
       If[0.8 < Ytt[beta, alpha, Y4] < 1.2,
        Sow[{beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms, fsigma[beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms]}]
        ],
       {beta, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[2.], 0.1},
       {alpha, ArcTan[0.1], ArcTan[0.3], 0.1},
       {Y4, -1, -5, -1},
       {xx, -7, 7, 1},
       {ms, 350, 400, 50}
       ]
      ][[2, 1]];~Monitor~{beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms};
Export["results.dat", results, "Table"]
```

Comment: @S.S. Sorry, see edit.  Try `Export["results.dat", results, "Table"]`

Comment: I found results.dat has been made , but only with one word "Table".

Comment: Thanx, it's working now.

Comment: @ JasonB. Can I set extra constrain on `fsigma[beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms]` to list only the values where `fsigma[beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms] > 0` ?

Comment: @S.S. Easy, just use `(0.8 < Ytt[beta, alpha, Y4] < 1.2)&&fsigma[beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms] >0`

Comment: @ JasonB.  Can we use `Select` instead after generating all the data sample ?

Comment: @S.S. `Select[ results, (fsigma@@@#[[;;-1]]>0 &)]` would work I think

Comment: @S.S. Can't edit that comment, but I think it has 1 too many @ symbols

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40072/discussion-between-s-s-and-jasonb).

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off using something like `Table` than an explicit `For` or `Do` loop (I believe this is often the case in MMA). e.g:

```
Table[{
    beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms, 
    If[ 0.8 <= Ytt[beta, alpha, Y4] < 1.2, fsigma[beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms] , 0]},
  {beta, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[2.], 0.1},
  {alpha, ArcTan[0.1], ArcTan[0.3], 0.1}, 
  {Y4, -1, -5, -1},
  {xx, -7, 7, 1},
  {ms, 350, 400, 50}
]
```

Comment: I think it's better to use a loop, for my expressions

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon the answers so far you may have a nice format for output on screen (e.g. [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)) and get your file as you want it.

### Creating a Dataset

```
data = Table[
    (* List elements *)
    If[ 0.8 <= Ytt[ beta, alpha, Y4 ] < 1.2,
        (* then *) Association[
            "beta" -> beta,
            "alpha" -> alpha,
            "Y4" -> Y4,
            "xx" -> xx,
            "ms" -> ms,
            "fsigma" -> fsigma[ beta, alpha, Y4, xx, ms ]
        ],
        (* else *) Nothing (* which is automatically removed *)
    ],
    (* iterator specification *)
    {beta, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[2.], 0.1},
    {alpha, ArcTan[0.1], ArcTan[0.3], 0.1}, 
    {Y4, -1, -5, -1},
    {xx, -7, 7, 1},
    {ms, 350, 400, 50}
] // RightComposition[
        Flatten[ #, 2]&, (* bring the Table-results to just 2 levels and have Nothing removed *)
        Dataset
    ]
```

### Exporting the Values to a File

Using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) and [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) you can use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to export the revant values to a .dat file as demonstrated by JasonB.

```
(* SetDirectory[ NotebookDirectory[] ] or something else if needed *)
Export[ "data.dat", data[[ All, Values ]]//Normal, "Table" ]
```

Comment: If you would like to view the dataset but find it is too large, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61030/764) will help.