# Capture/Save Manipulate[Select[dataset to Usable File Format

Tags: manipulate

Using the following code generates a view of exactly what I was seeking, 'manipulating' a large spreadsheet/table:

```
dataset = Dataset[SemanticImport["C:/Downloads/_22702_6.xlsx"]];

Manipulate[Select[dataset,

#"rr_Count"                          > c01        &&
#"rr_Slope_5050x_3"                  > c02        &&
#"rr_Slope_5050x_5"                  > c03        &&
#"rr_Sen_Slope_5050x_5"              > c04        &&
#"rr__50503"                         > c05        &&
#"rr__50505"                         > c06        &],

{{c01, 10, "Count of Occurrences"    }, 1, 100, 1},
{{c02, 80, "Slope_5050x_3"           }, 1, 100, 1},
{{c03, 80, "Slope_5050x_5"           }, 1, 100, 1},
{{c04, 80, "Sen_Slope_5050x_5"       }, 1, 100, 1},
{{c05, 80, "50503"                   }, 1, 100, 1},
{{c06, 80, "50505"                   }, 1, 100, 1}]
```

After finally getting it to work (thanks @Kuba)..., I'm finding no way to save the results, in a usable format, such as Excel, etc.  Best offered is, seems, Enhanced Metafile graphic form.

Yikes!!

Is there concurrence on here that no way exists to capture/save, to then use further??

And, a follow-up question, please.  How can I show in the output more than the 20 lines (default).  I think I read somewhere that showing more lines is possible.  I'd prefer to show ALL lines matching the criteria.

Insights greatly appreciated.

Nicholas Kormanik

[image: "Manipulate, Select, Dataset.png"]

Comment: you can add `var = Select[....` and then export var however you like. About additional question: [**61030**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61030/5478). Is that enough?

Comment: p.s. one can find 3 questions here. Please stress the main one out and try to not ask many questions at once. (secondary/additional are usually tolerated unless they influence whose answer you accept etc.)

Comment: Well, @Kuba, seems too complicated to decipher.  Plus they appear to be referring to earlier versions of Mma.  What I note, though, is that others are complaining about this same thing, wanting a non-truncated dataset view.  Sheeesh.  Please explain the best solution at present, if you feel like it.

Comment: Okay, @Kuba, I got it.  Thanks a million for the lead.  So, prior to evaluating the Manipulate cell, evaluate the following: Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount = 100; to show 100 rows of the dataset.  Phew....