# Capture/Save Manipulate[Select[dataset to Usable Format (revisited)

Tags: manipulate

I asked before, but didn't get an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138815/capture-save-manipulateselectdataset-to-usable-file-format) I could understand.

I am using Manipulate[Select[ on a dataset, and need to use the results.  One cannot simply copy/paste these results.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Was Kuba's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138815/capture-save-manipulateselectdataset-to-usable-file-format#comment374840_138815) not a sufficient answer this question?  Use `Manipulate[ result = Select[ ... ], ... ]`, then you can use `result` later in your notebook.  The value of `result` will get updated whenever you change the `Manipulate` controls.

Comment: I tried Kuba's "add var = Select[...." the only place where it seemed to make sense: " `result = Manipulate[Select[dataset` " and that didn't work.  I didn't try the clearer approach you show above.  Will try it.  Thank you.

Comment: Then not sure how one would use "result" to then subsequently show the spreadsheet, as the "Paste Snapshot" approach does.

Comment: What if you just evaluate `result` in a subsequent cell?  It should show the dataset, similarly to the display inside `Manipulate` at the very bottom of the screenshot in your original question.  If all you need is to use the result of `Manipulate', this should be much easier (and more robust, if you change things later) than copying and pasting.

Comment: Not sure how one could evaluate `result`.  What would be the code for that?  `result = what`?

Comment: Just type `result` in a new cell (all by itself) and evaluate (Shift+Enter).  The output will be your displayed dataset.  Since `result` is a variable with a value, evaluating `result` by itself will simply display that value.

Comment: Phew.  That works.  Easier than using "Paste Snapshot" from tiny icon at far, far right.  Thank you!

Comment: Next question becomes, how to transfer `result` to another program, such as Excel.  Manipulate seems oriented mostly for graphics.  Transferring graphics has several examples on these forums.  But case at hand is transferring the table, or spreadsheet.  Only way I have found so far is to highlight cell, and copy as Plain Text.  If there is another way, hope to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to results of Manipulate for subsequent use....

Click on far right-hand tiny icon in output.  "Paste Snapshot."

This pastes the 'Snapshot' into subsequent cell.

Then Evaluate that new cell.

Result is copyable.  Highlight cell, right border.  Copy as text.  (Unfortunately some additional junk, several lines, gets copied as well, and must be deleted from wherever you copy to.)

Example In[ ] after Paste Snapshot:

```
DynamicModule[{c01 = 2, c02 = 80, c03 = 80, c04 = 80, c05 = 80, 
  c06 = 80, c07 = 80, c08 = 80, c09 = 80}, 
 Select[dataset, #"r_Number" > c01 && #"r_Sen_Slope_5050x_3" > 
     c02 && #"r_Sen_Slope_5050x_5" > c03 && #"r_Mean_50503" > 
     c04 && #"r_Mean_50505" > c05 && #"r_Sen_Slope_5040x_3" > 
     c06 && #"r_Sen_Slope_5040x_5" > c07 && #"r_Mean_50403" > 
     c08 && #"r_Mean_50405" > c09 &]]
```

Then Evaluate this cell.

There might be other ways to achieve copyable results.  If so please chime in here....