# Displaying more columns of a dataset

Tags: output-formatting, dataset

How can I request (programmatically or otherwise) the display of more `Dataset` columns?

For example, this command displays only 10 of the 13 columns of the dataset:

```
ds = ResourcedFunction["ExampleDataset"][{"Statistics", "LakeMeadLevels"}]
```

Can I get Mathematica to show, say, at most 20 dataset columns?

---

I can "force" the display of all columns (and rows) with the function
[`GridTableForm`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GridTableForm) from the Wolfram Function Repository:

```
ResourceFunction["GridTableForm"][Normal@ds[Values], TableHeadings -> Normal[Keys[ds[[1]]]]]
```

I am looking for a (concise) `Dataset` solution.

---

I know there are (multiple) MSE questions/answers about
[showing more dataset rows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61030).
I hope similar solutions exist about columns.

Comment: Try: `Dataset[ds, MaxItems -> {Automatic, All}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks! Please submit an answer. (And, yes, [`MaxItems`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxItems.html) is linked in 'Dataset`'s function page.)

Comment: To the person who proposed this question to be closed as "easily found in the documentation" -- maybe that is true, but I googled/searched for more than 5-10 minutes without finding relevant answers. I was getting lots of MSE hits, though, for increasing the number of rows (displayed by `Dataset`.) So, I think having an "increased Dataset columns" question with an answer is useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Dataset` and the option `MaxItems -> {Automatic, All}`:

```
Dataset[ds, MaxItems -> {Automatic, All}]
```

[image]

See [`MaxItems`'s function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxItems.html).