# How to show complete dataset?

Tags: dataset

```
<|{{1, "u"}, {1, "u"}} -> {{0}}, {{1, "d"}, {1, 
     "u"}} -> {{2 (f - g Cos[p])}}|> // Dataset
```

gives

[image]

All the items are incomplete. How to show them completely.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54607/57

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Are you sure that will work this out? I think they different. There are too many answer. and I tried one, it just add rows, not expanding the rows

Comment: There are many answers in these two links that seem to address your problem. If you have only tried one, you haven't tried enough.