# How to correctly show plots in Dataset?

Tags: plotting, dataset

I want to show plots in Dataset. Something like this

```
Table[<|"a" -> 
    ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 10], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200],
   "b" -> 
    ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, 10], Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 200]|>, {i, 1, 5}] // Dataset
```

will give

[image]

You can see

1. the Frame is not showing
2. ImageSize is not working

How to correctly show plots in Dataset?

Comment: e.g., `ds[5, 2] // Normal` indicates that it has been stored correctly and the `Frame` is also there. A related discussion on dataset formatting is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54607/mathematica-10-dataset-doesnt-format-more-than-4-columns/54636#54636)

Comment: @Syed Thank you, I came up with a solution

Comment: I learned a new feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a solution using `ItemDisplayFunction`

Define

```
data=Table[<|
"a"->ListPlot[RandomReal[1,10],Frame->True,ImageSize->200],
"b"->ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1,10],Frame->True,ImageSize->200]|>,{i,1,5}];
```

then

```
dset=Dataset[data, ItemDisplayFunction -> (StandardForm[#] &)]
```

[image]

However, if we select two rows,

```
dset[[{1,2}]]
```

still gives

[image]

For this, I can only solve it awkwardly by `Normal` and `Dataset` again like

```
Dataset[Normal@dset[[{1,2}]],ItemDisplayFunction -> (StandardForm[#] &)]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: You can use `SetOptions` to include that option everytime you use `Dataset`. For example: `SetOptions[Dataset, ItemDisplayFunction -> (StandardForm[#] &)]` or `SetOptions[Dataset, ItemDisplayFunction -> (Pane[#] &)]`

Comment: @chuy Hi. Thank you for reply. It would be a much better solution. However, I tried your solution, it didn't work